# How to resolve time-exceeded error(codechef) for stable-marraige?

Tags: java, arrays, linked-list

I am trying to implement the stable marriage using lists and arrays. When i try to submit it on codechef it gives runtime exceeded errors.If someone could help but i want to use the very same data-structure i am using.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

private int size;
private static LinkedList<Integer>[] menlist;
private static int[][] womatrix;
private static int[][] invwomatrix;
private static int[] womatch;
private static int[] menmatch;
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int TestCases = Input.nextInt();
    while(TestCases-- > 0) {
        int size = Input.nextInt();
        womatrix=new int[size][size];
        invwomatrix=new int[size][size];
        menlist=new LinkedList[size];
        womatch=new int[size];
        menmatch=new int[size];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
             int temp=Input.nextInt();
             for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
             {
                        womatrix[i][j] = Input.nextInt();
                        invwomatrix[i][womatrix[i][j]-1]=j+1;
             }
             }
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
             int temp=Input.nextInt();
             LinkedList<Integer> menpref = new LinkedList<Integer>();
             for(int j = 0; j < size; j++)
                {
                        int a=Input.nextInt();

                        menpref.add(a);

             }
             menlist[i]=menpref;
             }

        LinkedList<Integer> ll = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            womatch[i]=0;
            menmatch[i]=0;
            ll.add(i+1);
        }

        while((ll.isEmpty()!=true) || menlist[ll.getFirst()-1].isEmpty()!=true ){

            int newman=ll.removeFirst();
            //System.out.print("freeman "+newman+" "+menlist[newman-1].isEmpty()+"\n");
            int women=(menlist[newman-1].removeFirst());
            //System.out.print("highrank "+women+"intial_pair "+womatch[women-1]+"\n");
            if(womatch[women-1]==0){
                womatch[women-1]=newman;
                menmatch[newman-1]=women;
                //int a=ll.removeFirst();

            }
            else{
                int oldman=womatch[women-1];

                if(invwomatrix[women-1][newman-1]<invwomatrix[women-1][oldman-1]){
                    womatch[women-1]=newman;
                    menmatch[newman-1]=women;
                    ll.addFirst(oldman);

                }
                else{
                    ll.addFirst(newman);
                }
            }
            /*for(int i=0; i<this.size; i++) {
                System.out.print((i+1)+" "+ menmatch[i] +"\n");
                }*/

            if(ll.isEmpty()==true){break;}

        }

        for(int k=0;k<size;k++){
             System.out.print((k+1)+" "+menmatch[k] +"\n");
         }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: it would be good if you explained your logic also

Comment: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos423/lectures/01stable-matching.pdf. The one described here.the complexity should be O(n^2)